# What constraint am I missing for this SAT optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, constraints, python, satisfiability

I'm trying to solve a variation of the bin-packing problem. I have a certain floor space and I wish to place as many boxes as I can without stacking, i.e. if the floor is a 4 x 4 grid and I have one package that is 3 x 3 (A), one that is 3 x 1 (B), and one that is 1 x 4 (C) I could place them as such

$$
B B B C \\
AAAC \\
AAAC \\
AAAC. $$

So to solve this with SAT I have initialised a 4 x 4 grid with bools where each grid point is named $xyp$ where $x$ denotes the current x-value, $y$ the current y-value and $p$ is the package so A, B or C. So for example the bottom left grid point would be denoted 00A, 00B, and 00C in this example. The whole grid would be initialised for each package. \

As for the constraints I've defined them as such:

1. The first constraint is meant to denote where on the grid package A can be placed, and that it can only be placed once and is written as such

```
Or(And(00A, 01A, 02A, 10A, 11A, 12A, 20A, 21A, 22A),
  And(01A, 02A, 03A, 11A, 12A, 13A, 21A, 22A, 23A),
  And(10A, 11A, 12A, 20A, 21A, 22A, 30A, 31A, 3A0),
  And(11A, 12A, 13A, 21A, 22A, 23A, 31A, 32A, 33A))
```

2. The second constraint is meant to ensure no overlapping between the packages, so it goes through each grid point and ensures that no two packages are placed at the same spot. This is done as such

```
And(Not(And(00B, 00A)),
    Not(And(01B, 01A)),
    Not(And(02B, 02A)),
    Not(And(03B, 03A)), ... )
```

However, I'm having trouble with that this only works for small problems when I run it with Python (with z3Py if relevant). Once I get to a 14 x 14 grid I'm no longer getting feasible solutions even though they exist. So I'm wondering if I'm missing a constraint or have I formulated myself wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your Or statements represent all possible legal placements for A,B,C?

Comment: @copper.hat I think so, but I'll check again!

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, it represents all legal placements also for those grids where I don't get a feasible solution

Comment: Can you validate that your feasible satisfies all theconstraints? What answer does z3 give?

Comment: @saulspatz: It is true **iff** A occupies 33. The set of legal placements incorporate the shape implicitly.

Comment: @copper.hat Not sure I understand what you mean. The feasible solutions I get on the smaller grid do satisfy my constraints, but not there is apparently no feasible solution for larger grids. In z3 I use the s.check() to see if it's sat or unsat.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Are you saying that you have manually determined a feasible placement but check() returns infeasble??? What exactly does check() return?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110912/discussion-between-ella-and-copper-hat).